Call WCF service without knowing the contract type
I'm trying to implement health monitoring in WCF. To achieve this, server side, services which will use my custom service host, I'm adding "Ping" operation within existing contract operations.
On the client side, I'm trying to call dynamically added Ping operation without knowing the contact type. How can I call Ping method?
I've tried below at client side to achieve, but it isn't working
var channel = GetServiceProxy(); var result = channel.Ping();

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")] 
public interface IDynamicPing 
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "http://tempuri.org/Ping")] 
    string Ping(); 
}

public static IDynamicPing GetServiceProxy() 
{ 
    var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None); 
    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 9999999; 

    var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/SampleWcfCustomerService/Service.svc"); 

    ChannelFactory<IDynamicPing> factory = new ChannelFactory<IDynamicPing>(binding, endpoint); 

    return factory.CreateChannel(endpoint); 
}

Server side web.config looks like this:
<services>   
    <service name="SampleWcfServer.CustomerService">     
        <endpoint 
            address="" 
            binding="netNamedPipeBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="ClientBinding"
            contract="CommonServices.ICustomerService">     
        </endpoint>   
    </service> 
</services>

<bindings>   
    <netNamedPipeBinding>     
        <binding name="ClientBinding" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="9999999">       
            <security mode="None"></security>     
        </binding>   
    </netNamedPipeBinding> 
</bindings>

I'm getting this error while dynamically invoking added Ping operation:

The message with Action 'http://tempuri.org/Ping' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).'

Is there a way that I can call the service method without knowing the contract? OR is it possible using reflection?

According to the error, the binding or contract is inconsistent between the server-side and client-side. You can look at why the contract ICustomerService on the server-side is inconsistent with IDynamicPing on the client-side. And there is no IDynamicPing interface on the server-side.
